# Draw rectangle depending where the mouse is

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I think I have some difficulty to think through. I have a canvas surrounded by a border and I want to draw a rectangle around the mouse. My problem is, the mouse can move and what I want is like a datagrid. In example, in a datagrid, all cell are already visible, (I know I can make them invisible, that's not the point), but all the cell are static, what I'm trying to do is when I mouseover the canvas, the rectangle be drawned at a static position, sorry if I'm unclear. The picture under should be better.

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

So as you can see in the first picture my mouse is there and I get some value, what I would like is whenever I'm in the place where I get this value I draw a rectangle over it. As you can see in the second picture when I move my mouse a little bit, I'm still in the area where I have the same value so the rectangle would still be there, and on the third picture I've moved a little further and you see the x coordinate changes and the value also do change then the rectangle would have to be drawned again over the other part

My problem is I don't know how to draw a rectangle of 45 by 40 relative to the mouse but relative to the canvas because if the mouse it's at x : 0 Y : 0 then the rectangle would be 45 by 40 but if my mouse is at X : 10 Y : 10 then the rectangle would have to be, if the mouse is the start point of 10 up the mouse down of 30 and then 10  by left and 35 to the right, I've tried to be as clear as possible, if it's still confuse tell me I will do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirements easily using the [`TranslateTransform` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a couple of `double` properties:

```
<Rectangle Name="Rectangle" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{x:Null}">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding XTransform}" Y="{Binding YTransform}" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

You can handle the `UIElement.PreviewMouseMove` Event on the `Canvas` element and update your two transform properties from the handler... try something like this:

```
private void CanvasPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    XTransform = e.GetPosition(Rectangle).X;
    YTransform = e.GetPosition(Rectangle).Y;
}
```

Comment: Since I'm pretty to wpf, I don't understand the error your code is giving me, in the not xaml part, the compiler say xTransform is not declared in the current contex, how do I make so ?

Comment: I said *You can achieve your requirements easily using the TranslateTransform Class and a couple of double properties*... the important part... *and a couple of double properties*. I thought that it was clear, but the `XTransform` and `YTransform` *are those two properties that you need to add*. Then , by changing the values of those two properties, you'll be able to move the `Rectangle` around the `Canvas`.

Answer (score 0):

The MouseMove event fires whenever the mouse moves over an element.  If I understand your question, you want the know where the mouse is as it moves over the Canvas.  So add an event handler to the Canvas.  Be sure an name the canvas, you will need the name to refer to is in the mouse event handler.

**XAML**

```
 <Border Margin='20'
          BorderBrush='Orange'
          BorderThickness='2'>
    <Canvas x:Name='DrawingCanvas' 
            MouseMove='DrawingCanvas_MouseMove' 
            Background='Transparent'>
      <Rectangle x:Name='MouseRectangle'
                 Width='30'
                 Height='30' 
                 Stroke='Purple' 
                 StrokeThickness='2'  />
    </Canvas>

  </Border>
```

The MouseMove event provides the **MouseEventArgs** argument. Use it to get the mouse location relative to any element in the UI.  In your case, that would be the canvas.

**Code**

*Centers the Rectangle over the mouse tip*

```
 private void DrawingCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {

      Canvas.SetTop(MouseRectangle, 
                    e.GetPosition(DrawingCanvas).Y - MouseRectangle.Height/2);
      Canvas.SetLeft(MouseRectangle,
                     e.GetPosition(DrawingCanvas).X - MouseRectangle.Width /2);
    }
```